# how to pass props to react-native when using React native web?

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

When I use `react-native-web` , my App entry looks like the following

```
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('SnsAdvertiser', () => Advertiser)                                                                                                                                                                            
 AppRegistry.runApplication('SnsAdvertiser', { rootTag: document.getElementById('mainApp') });
```

I wonder how I can pass props to the root Component in this case `Advertiser` in this case in a web environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runApplication` accepts another parameter in the second argument called `initialProps` alongwith `rootTag`

```
 AppRegistry.runApplication('SnsAdvertiser', {
     rootTag: document.getElementById('mainApp'),
     initialProps: {...}
 });
```

Comment: From where did you get the reference of **AppRegistry.runApplication** parameters like **initialProps**

Comment: Reference of AppRegistry:
https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/?path=/docs/apis-appregistry--page