# how to pass props to react-native when using React native web server side rendering?

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829859/how-to-pass-props-to-react-native-when-using-react-native-web), my App entry looks like

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SnsAdvertiser', () => Advertiser)
const { element, getStyleElement } = AppRegistry.getApplication('App', { string: 'hello!' })
```

Instead of using runApplication, I am using getApplication which is

> getApplication: (key: string, params: AppParams) => ({ element, getStyleElement })

> A web-only method for server-side rendering to HTML and CSS. It returns an object containing the given application’s element and getStyleElement function to get styles once the element is rendered.

- https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/app-registry/#static-methods

The second argument of getApplication is params, but when I pass this in and log my props in my component, I get an empty object.

I'm wondering how I can pass props in a server environment.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1983) I realised I have to pass params like `{ initialProps: { string: 'hello!' } })`.